# Accessing another script in the same directory using python

Tags: python

Is there a way I can have a main script that can access other scripts in the same directory to run them at the correct time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found what I was looking for.
I just had to type 'import filename' without *.py and reload my main script in blender.